# How is a day 30 hours?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, self-answer

I had posted a [rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9678/six-rebus-puzzles-starting-with-three-windows) and users solved it. After all of them were solved, [I posted a CW answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9678/six-rebus-puzzles-starting-with-three-windows/9701#9701) with all the answers of the puzzle.
I tried to accept my answer after I posted it and a popup came with the following message:

> You can accept your own answer tomorrow

So, the next day, I saw `answered 22 hours ago` below the answer and when I clicked the accept button, this popup message came:

> You can accept your own answer in 8 hours

Isn't that popup message supposed to show `2 hours` instead of `8 hours` as a day consist of 24 hours? How is a day 30 hours?

Here is my answer(`7 hours` was `8 hours` a minute ago):

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-answers can only be accepted 2 days after the question is posted. You posted your question at 2015-02-28 13:57:02Z, and the self-answer at 2015-03-01 07:42:14Z, which was approximately 17.75 hours after the question was posted. Hence, you had 30.25 hours left to wait, which was "rounded" and displayed as one day.

Comment: That makes sense! I didn't know that self-answers can only be accepted 2 days after the question is posted. Thanks!